# Display the LinkedIn Profile/Company Updates (Timeline)

Tags: javascript, plugins, rss, linkedin-api, social-networking

I try to load some social profile timeline threads on my webpage.

for **[Twitter](https://publish.twitter.com/#)**, it has widgets that could be loaded from the settings page, and it goes on like

```html
<a class="twitter-timeline" href="https://twitter.com/TwitterDev?ref_src=twsrc%5Etfw">
    Tweets by TwitterDev
</a>
<script async src="https://platform.twitter.com/widgets.js" charset="utf-8">
</script>
```

but for the **LinkedIn**, it does not give a way (?) to display the company feed.

[image]

Answer (score -1):

A very very long loading solution (replace `COMPANY_ID` with the corresponding ID):

```
<div id="linkedin-content"></div>

<script>
$.get("https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/http://www.linkedin.com/biz/{COMPANY_ID}/feed?start=0&v2=true", function(data) {
    $("#linkedin-content").html($(data).find(".linkedin-article"));
});  
</script>
```